# Update view after applying rotation on one 3D object OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I have been working on an app based on the ARCore sample for Android Studio. I have managed to bring different objects of my choice in the view and now I am trying to rotate only one object, that being the last object placed. That means that when selecting an object, I should be able to rotate it and change its position, until I select another object. Than I shouldn't be able to manipulate that object anymore.
Now this is my draw() method that is called for every placed object

```
public void draw(float[] cameraView, float[] cameraPerspective, float lightIntensity) {

    ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "Before draw");

    // Build the ModelView and ModelViewProjection matrices
    // for calculating object position and light.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, cameraView, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, cameraPerspective, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);



    if(this.movable==true) {
      //rotation
      Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, FactorsClass.rotateF, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      Matrix.multiplyMM(mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
    }

    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    // Set the lighting environment properties.
    Matrix.multiplyMV(viewLightDirection, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0, LIGHT_DIRECTION, 0);
    normalizeVec3(viewLightDirection);
    GLES20.glUniform4f(
        lightingParametersUniform,
        viewLightDirection[0],
        viewLightDirection[1],
        viewLightDirection[2],
        lightIntensity);

    // Set the object material properties.
    GLES20.glUniform4f(materialParametersUniform, ambient, diffuse, specular, specularPower);

    // Attach the object texture.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);

    // Set the vertex attributes.
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
        positionAttribute, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, verticesBaseAddress);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalAttribute, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, normalsBaseAddress);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
        texCoordAttribute, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texCoordsBaseAddress);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Set the ModelViewProjection matrix in the shader.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, false, modelViewMatrix, 0);


      GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
      if(this.movable==true) {
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false, mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
      }


    // Enable vertex arrays
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribute);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttribute);

    if (blendMode != null) {
      GLES20.glDepthMask(false);
      GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
      switch (blendMode) {
        case Shadow:
          // Multiplicative blending function for Shadow.
          GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ZERO, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
          break;
        case Grid:
          // Grid, additive blending function.
          GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
          break;
      }
    }

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferId);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    if (blendMode != null) {
      GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
      GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    }

    // Disable vertex arrays
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribute);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttribute);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "After draw");
  }
```

At the moment, I can rotate an object as I wish (when the movable variable is true, meaning that it is the last object placed in the scene), but once I select another one, the old object returns to its initial position, as if it was never rotated. How can I update the matrix so that the rotations remain applied?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but once I select another one, the old object returns to its initial position, as if it was never rotated. How can I update the matrix so that the rotations remain applied?

I assume that `mRotationMatrix` is a member of the class. Ensure that `mRotationMatrix` is intilaized by the identity matrix.

Update `mRotationMatrix`, if `this.movable==true`, but use `mRotationMatrix` in any case to calculate `mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix`. Use `mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix` in any case to set `modelViewProjectionUniform`.

```
public void draw(float[] cameraView, float[] cameraPerspective, float lightIntensity) {

    .....

    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, cameraView, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, cameraPerspective, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);


    if(this.movable==true) {
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, FactorsClass.rotateF, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    .....

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false, mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);

    .....
}
```